# query the city field in Venue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I wrote this query for retrieving all the public events in Milan:

```
search?fields=name,venue&type=event&q=milan
```

But I need to query the city field in Venue. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

$fql_query = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=milan&type=event&'.$access_token;

This fql query will search all events that have a word "milan"

Comment: Do you know how to convert this query to fql query?